# Script access to tangent and bitangent, per face: how?

Tags: python, mesh

Suppose you have a mesh; you go into Edit mode, 
set Transform Orientation to Normal, 
show 3D manipulator widget,
Pivot Point = Active Element,
face select mode, and then you select any one face:
immediately you will see a blue arrow representing the face normal,
and also a red and a green arrow representing the face's tangent and bitangent.

What is the most straightforward way to refer 
to said tangent and bitangent vectors from a Python script?
The API documentation confuses me with loops and uv's, yet, clearly,
Blender assigns a tangent and bitangent to each face without hesitation!

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is 'calc_tangents'. http://elysiun.com/forum/showthread.php?338922-How-do-I-create-and-view-the-tangents-bitangents-for-a-mesh

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen!
To me, each face has a single loop that defines the perimeter, hence defines the face itself. But the API speaks of multiple loops, each with a single vertex??

Average, fine; thank you.
But Blender surely has a tangent and bitangent
already stored and associated with each face,
as evidenced by the instantaneous appearance of those little XYZ arrows when Transform Orientation = Normal.
Isn't that so?

Answer (score 7):

You access tangents and bitangents from [MeshLoops](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_8/bpy.types.MeshLoop.html):

```
import bpy
me = bpy.context.active_object.data

# tangents have to be pre-calculated
# this will also calculate loop normal
me.calc_tangents()

# loop faces
for face in me.polygons:
    # loop over face loop
    for vert in [me.loops[i] for i in face.loop_indices]:
        tangent = vert.tangent
        normal = vert.normal
        bitangent = vert.bitangent_sign * normal.cross(tangent)
```

To get tangent and bitangent of some face you need to average tangents and bitangents of every vertex in that face loop.

Comment: There is a convenience attribute on polygons you can use to loop over face loops: `face.loop_indices`. It's already a range object. `for vert in [me.loops[i] for i in face.loop_indices]:` should suffice.

Comment: Jerryno; CoDEmanX: face.loop_indices

Duly noted: thank you!

Comment: I made this test comparing normals coming from the loops and the ones that are stored in me.vertices[x].normal, and they are different. Shouldn't those be exactly the same? I've made a separate question here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71356/vertex-normals-different-from-loop-normals