# How to access/calculate tangent and bitangent vectors from BMLoop via script?

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

This question has an answer when using MeshLoops:
[Script access to tangent and bitangent, per face: how?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26116/script-access-to-tangent-and-bitangent-per-face-how)

But I'm working with BMLoops to collect vertex data. I haven't yet found a good way to calculate or access tangent/bitangent vectors using bmface/bmloop/etc.

I did find a possible solution, which is to just find the corresponding MeshLoop, but I'm not yet sure this works 100% of the time, and I feel like there should be a better way. (For this to work, all face and loop indices must match up between bmesh and mesh, I don't know if that is guaranteed?)

I've found and tried: BMLoop.calc_tangent(), but this appears to give the wrong vector (pointing towards the center of the face, not aligned with uv coordinates).  BMFace also has a few calc_tangent_*() function, but again, these don't appear to be the tangents I'm looking for.

Sample code:

```
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(me)

    me.calc_tangents()

    for face in bm.faces:
        for loop in face.loops:
            meshface = me.polygons[face.index]
            meshloop = me.loops[loop.index]
            tangent = meshloop.tangent
```